# Github Api v3 different callback responses

Tags: github, github-api-v3

I'm using github API in version 3, but request I send give me different results.

I want to retrieve top javascript repositories sorted by stars with that request:

https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:javascript&sort=stars&order=desc

Once at the first place is visible freeCodeCamp repository once vue once bootstrap.

Maybe I have used this API incorectly or I should not relly on official github API ?

Have you met such problem? Do you have some kind of solution for this?